# Generate all possible variable values in Python

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way of getting the following:

```
(False, False, False)
(False, False, True)
(False, True, False)
(False, True, True)
...
```

I have `n` variables, each taking a value `True` or `False`, how can I combine these? I was thinking of using `range(n)` and then checking the bits of generated integers, but this seems too hacky.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably simplest:

```
>>> list(itertools.product([False, True], repeat=3))

[(False, False, False),
 (False, False, True),
 (False, True, False),
 (False, True, True),
 (True, False, False),
 (True, False, True),
 (True, True, False),
 (True, True, True)]
```